# How to show ViewController from a non-ViewController helper class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Usually we call self.presentViewController(...) from some UIViewController object, but how to show a new view controller from a class type (static) function in a helper class which is not a UIViewController.

Comment: What is root class of your helper class?

Comment: @Tirth Nothing just a plain helper class

Comment: go to helper class .h file and see which class written in front of @interface helper class and tell me

Comment: @Tirth I am using Swift, no header file.

Comment: Doesn't matter which language you using. Every OO language class having at least one parent class. Now in swift check infront of @class directive which class ??

Comment: @class HelperClass : NSObject {} see this example this simple HelperClass inherit from NSObject. Same thing is in your code too. check it out.

Comment: AnyObject is the parent protocol of every class in Swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show your viewController from helper class as root view controller of navigationcontroller

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController*)[storyBoard
                                                               instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"RootNavigationController"]; //set storyboard ID to your root navigationController.

YourViewController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewController"]; // //set storyboard ID to viewController.
[controller setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:vc] animated:YES];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController=controller;
```

Answer (score 5):

Mayank Jain's answer in swift 4:

```
var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
var controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootNavigationController") as? UINavigationController
//set storyboard ID to your root navigationController.
var vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as? YourViewController
// //set storyboard ID to viewController.
controller?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = controller
```

Answer (score 0):

It is directly not possible, you always need a view controller/navigation controller instance. but there are some possible work around.

It depends on requirement, how you want to use it. some of suggestions -

1. application delegate's navigation controller is accessible everywhere, you can use it.

   ```
     YourAppDelegate *delegate = (YourAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   ```

   now you can use - `delegate.window.rootViewController.navigationController`
2. In helper method instance itself pass instance of navigation controller from where you are calling it.
   Some thing like -

   ```
   +(void)myHelperMethodWithNavigationController:(UINavigationController*)navController {
     -------
     [navController pushViewController:yourNewCreatedController animated:YES];
    }
   ```

   while calling this from some view controller -

   ```
   [MyHelperClass myHelperMethodWithNavigationController:self.navigationController];
   ```

Comment: Can you please complete the explanation by mentioning what to do after I get instance of navigationController?

Comment: Edited the post, its similar to concept of handling view controller hierarchy , once you have navigation controller you can push view controller on it, present some controller modally. also if you want to access current stack of view controller, you can access that.

Comment: as the documentation of pushViewController:animated: says that we can not add the viewController if it's already in the navigation stack. How can we be so sure about it? What to do if it's already there? What kind of check do we perform before pushing some view in navigation controller?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:

Comment: navController.viewControllers gives you array of all active view controller on this navigationStack, and if its already available you can reuse it/ remove it and create new one . But there are some instances when you have to keep different instance of same view controller and there is no issue in that as long as you are maintaining the stack properly.