# show view controller from custom class

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to show a view controller from a custom class. I looked at examples and I cannot figure it out. I gave the ViewControllers a storyboard id = main

```
class MyCustomClass {

}
```

and the class where I want to show

```
class ShowViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

I am using swift 4. Any help is much appreciated because all the examples either don't work or not in swift 4. What I mean by show is probably by performSegue()

Comment: The question isn't clear. What do you mean by custom class? Is it another view controller class? And you are trying to show a view controller from another view controller by segue?

Comment: its not another view controller class. If it was then this would be easy. Its a class that's not part of a view controller.

Comment: I would like to show a view from a class I defined that's not a view controller class.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure, but take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47026516/7808861). It may help you.